# Unable to find files/folders with permissions 777 by AWK/SED/Python

Tags: python, sed, awk

**Problems**

1. to get permissions
   of each file in every folder
2. to find files
   which have 777 permissions, and then
   print the filenames with their paths
   to a list

We can get permissions for files in one folder by

```
ls -ls
```

I do not know how you can get permissions of each file in every folder effectively.

**How can you find files which have permissions 777 by AWK/SED/Python?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for `find`?

```
find /some/path -perm 0777
```

Comment: How can I change the permissions for each file which match the criterion? I tried $ find * -perm 777 | chmod 770 unsuccessfully.

Comment: I found the following code $ find * -perm 777 -exec chmod 770 {} \; It seems to work.

Comment: And find ... | xargs chmod 770 also works.  Look up xargs.  And if you have spaces in your file names, use find ... -print0 | xargs -0

Answer (score 4):

find /some/path -perm 0777 -type f